# How to access web API server running on Windows with Iphone that is connected on a Macbook in C#

Tags: c#, ios, api, http, maui

I'm buidling a blazor hybrid project and I want to test my application on an Iphone.
The Iphone is connected with a Macbook. The Macbook is connected in Visual studio using the Paired to Mac method.
I have an API project that is running in the background to receive calls from their specific endpoints. On an android real device and android emulators everything is working fine but I know with IOS this doesn't work the same. The API calls are not getting hit once I deployed the app on an Iphone.
So what I want to achieve is to connect to local web services (on my windows machine) from iOS real device that is connected with a mac book.
This is what I currently have :

MauiProgram.cs

```
private static HttpClient BuildHttpClient()
        {
            string url = DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.Android ? "https://10.0.2.2:7128" : "https://localhost:7128";

#if DEBUG
            HttpsClientHandlerService handler = new HttpsClientHandlerService();
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler.GetPlatformMessageHandler()) { BaseAddress = new Uri(url) };
#else
            client = new HttpClient(BaseAddress = new Uri(url));
#endif
            return client;
        }
```

HttpsClientHandlerService

```
public class HttpsClientHandlerService
    {
        public HttpMessageHandler GetPlatformMessageHandler()
        {
#if ANDROID
            var handler = new CustomAndroidMessageHandler();
            handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) =>
            {
                if (cert.Issuer.Equals("CN=localhost"))
                    return true;
                return errors == System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.None;
            };
            return handler;
#elif IOS
            var handler = new NSUrlSessionHandler
            {
                TrustOverrideForUrl = IsHttpsLocalhost
            };
            return handler;


#else
            throw new PlatformNotSupportedException("Only Android and iOS supported.");
#endif
        }

#if IOS
        public bool IsHttpsLocalhost(NSUrlSessionHandler sender, string url, Security.SecTrust trust)
        {
            //if (url.StartsWith("https://localhost"))
            //    return true;
            return true;
        }
#endif
    }

#if ANDROID
    internal sealed class CustomAndroidMessageHandler : Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidMessageHandler
    {
        protected override Javax.Net.Ssl.IHostnameVerifier GetSSLHostnameVerifier(Javax.Net.Ssl.HttpsURLConnection connection)
            => new CustomHostnameVerifier();

        private sealed class CustomHostnameVerifier : Java.Lang.Object, Javax.Net.Ssl.IHostnameVerifier
        {
            public bool Verify(string hostname, Javax.Net.Ssl.ISSLSession session)
            {
                return Javax.Net.Ssl.HttpsURLConnection.DefaultHostnameVerifier.Verify(hostname, session) ||
                    hostname == "10.0.2.2" || hostname == Constants.Hostname && session.PeerPrincipal?.Name == "CN=localhost";
            }
        }
    }
```

launchSettings.json in the API project

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:28563",
      "sslPort": 44342
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "EventApplicationAPI": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:7128;http://10.100.0.152:7128",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Changing the ip address if the app is running on an ios device. Tried using ngrok as well but without positive results

Comment: use the IP or FQDN of the server, not `localhost`.  Be sure your web server is setup to handle remote requests

Comment: @Jason Tried that but didn't work

Comment: "didn't work" is not a very helpful description of the problem.  Did you get an error or exception?  Have you verified connectivity from your device to the server using the web browser on the device?  Have you checked that there are no firewall issues?  Are you sure your local server is configured to accept remote requests?

Comment: I don't get errors and I can't get connectivity from my device to the api server. That's the core of my question on how I can get a connection with my api server that is on windows to my iphone connected to a mac. How can I check if my api server accepts remote requests?

Comment: Your phone is connecting over WiFI, it shouldn't matter if it is connected to the Mac or not.  I don't have any idea what local server you are using - google "server_name remote requests".

Comment: The server I'm using is a local API server with Swagger (ASP.NET Core Web API)

Comment: I don't know what a "local API server" is.  If you mean the built in VS dev server, as I suggested before, google it.  There are numerous posts about how to config for remote connections.